# Python pandas dataframe groupby columns error no apply member

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to get the average price and total quantity of a dataset.
The code works, but I get the following error message:

**Instance of 'DataFrameGroupBy' has no 'apply' member** for the line

*summary_Report = df.groupby('name').apply(f1)*

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = [

        {'name': 'A', 'Quantity': 37, 'Price': 10},
        {'name': 'B', 'Quantity': 20, 'Price': 10.5},
        {'name': 'A', 'Quantity': 17, 'Price': 9},
        {'name': 'D', 'Quantity': 19, 'Price': 5},
        {'name': 'E', 'Quantity': 30, 'Price': 6}
    ]

def f1(x):
    d={}
    d['Total_Quantity']=x['Quantity'].sum()
    d['Average_Price']= ((x['Quantity'] * x['Price']).sum())/x['Quantity'].sum()
    return pd.Series(d, index=['Total_Quantity', 'Average_Price'])

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
summary_Report = df.groupby('name').apply(f1)
print(summary_Report)
```

Do you know how to solve this error message?

I am using Visual Studio Code. Already using the latest pandas version. See screenshot below for the error message. Using panda version 1.1.1.

[image]

Comment: Where are you running this code ? I get no errors and your code works

Comment: It is working fine. I couldn't found any errors !

Comment: Running this code from Visual Studio Code, using python version 3.8.5 64 bits, in windows 10, panda version 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

The code is running absolutely fine for me. But there can be a few potential issues -

1. You have used groupby as a variable name and overwritten the pandas method. Please restart the kernel and run again and it should not throw this error again.
2. You are working with an experimental version or outdated version of pandas. Please use `pip install --upgrade pandas` to update your pandas to a stable version.

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = [

        {'name': 'A', 'Quantity': 37, 'Price': 10},
        {'name': 'B', 'Quantity': 20, 'Price': 10.5},
        {'name': 'A', 'Quantity': 17, 'Price': 9},
        {'name': 'D', 'Quantity': 19, 'Price': 5},
        {'name': 'E', 'Quantity': 30, 'Price': 6}
    ]

def f1(x):
    d={}
    d['Total_Quantity']=x['Quantity'].sum()
    d['Average_Price']= ((x['Quantity'] * x['Price']).sum())/x['Quantity'].sum()
    return pd.Series(d, index=['Total_Quantity', 'Average_Price'])

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
summary_Report = df.groupby('name').apply(f1)
print(summary_Report)
```

```
      Total_Quantity  Average_Price
name                               
A               54.0       9.685185
B               20.0      10.500000
D               19.0       5.000000
E               30.0       6.000000
```